# Extract img attribute from html

Tags: jquery

I'm using revolution slider. When the slider changes, I want to grab the "id" attribute of the `<img>` tag and use it for further processing.

This is all I have so far:

```
revapi.on('revolution.slide.onafterswap', function(event, data) {
    var html = data.currentslide.html();
    alert(html);
});
```

This alerts the following (simplified):

```
<div class="slotholder">
    <img src="aa5.jpg" class="rev-slidebg aSliderImage defaultimg" id="aSliderImage_2_3">
    <div class="tp-bgimg defaultimg" style="background-image: url(&quot;aa5.jpg&quot;);">
    </div>
</div>
```

I specifically need

```
id="aSliderImage_2_3"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `data.currentslide.html()` is returning string. So wrap it with `$(...)` will convert it into object and you can perform `find` on it.

```
revapi.on('revolution.slide.onafterswap', function(event, data) {
    var img = $(data.currentslide.html()).find("img");
    alert(img.attr("id"));
});
```

**Edit 1**

Updated `find` selector. Hopefully this could work for your complicated object.

```
revapi.on('revolution.slide.onafterswap', function(event, data) {
    var img = $(data.currentslide.html()).find("img.aSliderImage:first");
    alert(img.attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: I think it returned undefined because the actual html is much more complicated than I used in my original post. I have tried the simplified html and it DOES work. So, I will just play with it until it works with the complicated code.

Comment: `$(data.currentslide.html())` will return regular `jQuery` object as you perform on `DOM`. So you can use any `jquery` `selectors` like `.class` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just go further into your HTML and find the `<img>`, then alert the `id` attribute:

```
revapi.on('revolution.slide.onafterswap', function(event, data) {
    var html = data.currentslide.html().filter("img");
    alert(html.attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: I tried that and I get the error "data.currentslide.html(...).find is not a function"

Comment: Changed it now, any better @user460114

Comment: Error: data.currentslide.html(...).filter is not a function